# Determining photo is geotagged?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, photos, geotag, josm

I use a android app called OSMTracker. This app records the GPS track and can take pictures and notes. Using JOSM software, the photos are shown exactly at their coordinates (location) but i cannot use these photos in other GIS softwares like QGIS, it says **no geotagged photos in the location**.

How can i find out whether a photo is geotagged or not? I know that the information is written in some EXIF header, but i don't have any other files. I only have the GPS track and the photos.

If the photos are not geotagged, can i geotag them using the GPS track?

Comment: The EXIF header is part of the image file itself. If being reported as missing by QGIS then OSMTracker might not be setting the EXIF header.

Comment: If the camera and the GPS track have (approximately) synchronized clocks (which would be the case if the camera and the GPS are both your phone/android device), you can interpolate the track locations to estimate the location where the photo was taken.

Comment: To pick up Llaves comment, camera and GPS clocks run at different rates, about 2-3 seconds per day, so you need to adjust the timestamp in the photos back to gps time before geotagging if you use a separate GPS.  My cameras get up to 5 minutes out of sync.  You also need to have a track with lots of track points (from time based point creation) or use interpolation between points rather than using last known position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Windows, in File Explorer, you look at the file details,

right click goto properties then to get advanced options. In the details tab scroll down to gps section. If the EXIF data is present, there will be an index entry and the gps values, otherwise not

Comment: Sounds good. But say I have about 5000 photos that I want to check in a batch. How do we do this programmatically? I tried using [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to list all photos that have "GPSVersionID" tag, but it seems that even photos that aren't geotagged do have this tag. What would be the best tag to do a query on? Here is the list: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html

Comment: I found out that the "GPSTimeStamp" tag is present **only** when a photo is geotagged. If it helps anyone, here is the command that I used to determine which photos in a folder are geotagged (in Windows cmd): `exiftool -r -s -GPSTimeStamp "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures\folder_with_pictures" > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\photos_with_gps_tag.txt"`. Open the file *photos_with_gps_tax.txt* on your Desktop. All photos will be listed, but only photos that are geotagged will contain GPSTimeStamp tag information.

Comment: **Wrong.** Use "GPSLatitude" tag. Logically, if a photo is geotagged it would contain latitude and longitude data.

Answer (score 1):

Upload it to http://www.geotagmyphoto.com. If it is geotagged it will display the location on a Google map.